# in rx.js make source.subscribe await it's observer using async/await

Tags: javascript, async-await, rxjs

I have an observer that goes like this.

```
var source = rx.Observable.fromEvent(eventAppeared.emitter, 'event')
      .filter(mAndF.isValidStreamType)
      .map(mAndF.transformEvent)
      .share();
```

I then share it with a number of subscribers.  These subscribers all take the event and perform some async operations on them.
so my subscribers are like

```
 source.subscribe(async function(x) {
  const func = handler[x.eventName];
  if (func) {
    await eventWorkflow(x, handler.handlerName, func.bind(handler));
  }
});
```

There's a bit of extra stuff in there but I think the intent is clear.
I need every "handler" that handles this particular event to handle it and block till it gets back.  Then process the next event.

What I've found with the above code is that it's just calling the event with out awaiting it and my handlers are stepping on themselves.

I've read a fair number of posts, but I can't really see how to do it.  Most people are talking about making the observer awaitable.  But that's not what I need is it?  It seems like what I need is to make the observer awaitable.  I can't find anything on that which usually means it's either super easy or a super ridiculous thing to do.  I'm hoping for the former.

Please let me know if you need any further clarification.

---update---

what I have realized is that what I need is a fifo queue or buffer ( first in first out ), sometimes referred to as back pressure. I need all messages processed in order and only when the preceding message is done processing.

---end update---

at first I thought it was cuz I was using rx 2.5.3 but I just upgraded to 4.1.0 and it's still not synchronous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So ultimately what I have found is that what I need is more accurately described as a fifo queue or buffer.  I need the messages to wait until the previous message is done processing.

I have also pretty certain that rxjs doesn't offer this ( sometimes referred to as backpressure ).  So what I have done is to just import a fifo queue and hook it to each subscriber.

I am using concurrent-queue which so far seems to be working pretty well.

Answer (score 3):

There's no way to tell a source observable to put events on hold from within a `subscribe`, it just lets us "observe" incoming events. Asynchronous things should be managed via Rx operators.

For example, to let your asynchronous handlers process events sequentially, you could try to use `concatMap` operator:

```
source
    .concatMap(x => {
        const func = handler[x.eventName];
        return func ?
            eventWorkflow(x, handler.handlerName, func.bind(handler)) :
            Rx.Observable.empty();
    })
    .subscribe();
```

Note that in the example above `await` is not needed as `concatMap` knows how to deal with a promise which `eventWorkflow` returns: `concatMap` converts it to an observable and waits until the observable completes before proceeding with the next event.

Comment: Hi, thank you that is very detailed and helpful.  Would you say that concatmap is the correct pattern here?  It's kind of fundamental to my application.  I would be willing to refactor deeper if there is a more standard way to do it.

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't work for my purposes.  it's processing all of the events immediately and then letting the async work and returning the values.  What I need is for each event to be processed one at a time in order

Comment: Hi, Raif. Could you please elaborate a bit on what exactly goes wrong? Do you need some sort of backpressure, i.e. "pausing" of the source observable while a particular handler processes an event? Or do you just need your source events to be processed in order? If so, then `concatMap` allows exactly that (a contrived example here: http://jsbin.com/mugeki/edit?js,console). You also mentioned that there are several subscribers to the same source stream, do handlers of different subscribers be synchronized as well, meaning no two handlers work in parallel even for different subscribers?

Comment: Hi, you are right that concatMap will make sure they process in order, however I need the to process only when the preceding message has completed.  I updated my question.  I also answered my question.  And while I thank you for your help, I have to mark my answer as solving my problem.  But I will upvote yours :)